# Take a screenshot of BIOS

Tags: screenshot

I am working on a project at work where I am documenting steps on how to set up new computers for deployment to the field. For a couple of the steps, the techs need to go into the BIOS to change settings so that the computers work with the network we have here.

The problem is, I can't take screenshots of the BIOS screen to show them what settings to change. I have tried to simply take a picture of the screen, but that doesn't turn out good and looks really sloppy.

I am looking for an application/software that will allow me to take a screenshot of the BIOS to put into the techs setup documentation. I would like it to:

- Free or relatively cheap
- Be able to save the screenshot immediately (I don't want to have to boot into Windows to save the screenshot as a file)
- Capture the whole BIOS screen, not just what is showing on the monitor (Some pages scroll past the bottom of the screen and I need to capture the whole page)

Comment: Any specific OS you are using or you are open to any OS?

Comment: The computers have Windows 7 on them, but I could easily put another OS one of the computers to use the software

Comment: Ok, one last question, do you need this temporary, or you want to take bios screencaptures for ever? cuz you don't want a premium software, my solution is premium software, and its not that cheap

Comment: Right now it is temporary because I only need to take about 10 screenshots, but if we upgrade to new computers or need to make BIOS changes, we would need it in the future too.

Comment: Related: [windows 7 - How can I take screenshots of the PC before it boots up? - Super User](http://superuser.com/questions/290432/how-can-i-take-screenshots-of-the-pc-before-it-boots-up)

Comment: Yea I similarly took Screenshots of BIOS using VM Ware, and hence, I asked you about the temporary thing, if you want, you can use the trial software

Comment: @Mr.Alien Would taking a screenshot in a VM capture the motherboard BIOS screen or just the startup process?

Comment: @bobSmith1432 I have taken for installation but I think you can take the screens of Settings as well, or use IP KVM Switch

Comment: "tried to simply take a picture of the screen" - just curious what you tried? You should be able to get reasonable results on a tripod with a longer exposure, no external lighting?

Comment: The BIOS in VMware IS NOT THE SAME AS THE BIOS ON THE COMPUTER, DO NOT - I REPEAT, NOT - USE THAT FOR YOUR DOCUMENTATION! (wrote this in caps so it gets noticed quicker) AFAIK, a program that meets your requirements doesn't exist

Comment: You could try this, I think it depends whether you have a UEFI BIOS and supporting manufacturer, but it won't do any harm to try! http://techforum4u.com/entry.php/3422-How-To-Take-Screenshots-Of-Your-BIOS

Comment: Is it a legacy or UEFI BIOS? If it's a legacy BIOS and it doesn't have a screenshot feature (and I've never seen one), you're out of luck, period. If it's a UEFI BIOS, it might be hackable, but it's a long shot. You might install an alternate BIOS, of course (if you find one, which isn't a given), but that would defeat the purpose of illustrating the setup of a standard machine. What brand and model of computer(s) are you dealing with? What brand and model of BIOS?

Comment: @Mr.Alien VMWare **cannot** capture the screens of the motherboard BIOS, at best it can allow you to capture the emulated BIOS of the virtual machine (which is different).

Answer (score 27):

What you are asking for here is not physically possible.<sup>1</sup> If your target BIOS does not have a built in way to capture screen-shots, there is no  way for an external piece of software to do so.

- The BIOS in most PCs runs below everything else on the system.
- Although the data registers can sometimes be accessed, it is not possible to access the BIOS application interface from a higher level in the system (such as from inside an Operating System)
- The BIOS itself is incapable of running external applications.

What you expect to have happen simply won't work. You need to look into alternative solutions. There are at least three ways you could approach this:

1. **A BIOS Emulator**

   Not to be confused with a Virtual Machine! Most VM systems have BIOS'es of their own that interface between the guest operating system and the host virtualization software, but this is not the same thing as your computers BIOS. Any screen-shots you take of that will be of the VM software's pretend BIOS, not the real one on your system. They are almost certainly quite different.

   What you need is a specialty piece of software for emulating the specific BIOS of the machines you are targeting. These exist for many BIOS manufactures and can often read the BIOS flash update files, open them up and run them it a test environment. Basically this is a Virtual Machine host specifically for BIOSes. However, these are very specific to the make and model of your BIOS manufacture. As these vary widely you will need to look into the exact make of motherboard you need to give out instructions for and find and emulator for than BIOS.
2. **Video Output Capture**

   This is a hardware rather than software solution, but one way to accomplish this would be with a video capture device that you plug in in place of a monitor. For example a VGA2USB capture device or a network enabled remote KVM controller would allow you to read and record the actual picture being sent out on the video output (to what the BIOS assumes is a monitor).
3. **Cheat**

   Use somebody else's screen-shots. Google image search is your friend here, as are PDF manuals from motherboard manufactures. You can usually find shots of any screen in almost any BIOS system floating around out there already. They won't have your settings, but they will show the screen layout and you can either Photoshop them to read the way you want them to or simply annotate them with an overlay pointing out where changes should be made.

What solution you settle on will depend in large part how much time and effort you want to sink into this and how important it is to capture the exact configuration as used on your target systems.

One final word of warning: *Do not rely entirely on screenshots for this!* Of course the screenshots will make it a lot easier for most people to follow along, but if you fail to also write good copy that describes the steps that must be taken, the end result will be brittle and self-obsoleting. BIOS updates will come along with slightly different layouts and obsolete your screen-shots. People will end up with different motherboards than the ones you targeted and won't know what setting they are even looking for. Unicorns will be lost in space with no oxygen masks.<sup>2</sup> Screenshots should be a supplement to not a replacement for real instructional copy.

<sub><sup>1</sup> At least for most legacy BIOSes; newer UEFI systems make this technologically possible but I don't know of any implementations yet.</sub>

<sub><sup>2</sup> Just checking you are actually reading rather than just skimming. This warning is important, don't skip it.</sub>

Answer (score 3):

## Scanbot ([iOS](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/scanbot-scanner-app-scan-pdf), [Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.doo.snap&hl=en_US))

Mobile apps count as "software" right?

A quick-and-dirty way to get a *relatively* clean screenshot is to use a scanning app and your smartphone's camera. The app will automatically clean up the image so it doesn't have the weird rainbow artifacts you get if you just take a photo of the screen.

### Pros

- Free (assuming you have a smartphone)
- Fast
- Looks way better than a photo
- Looks almost as good as a real screenshot?

### Cons

- Not quite as good as a "real" screenshot
- No way to capture the entire page if you need to scroll past the bottom of the screen

### Example:

[image: Example of BIOS screenshot taken with Scanbot app]